# Getting an error when I nest a for-loop inside an if-else statement

Tags: windows, bash, scripting, git-bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script with a for-loop inside an if-else statement. The following code works:

```
if [ $# -le 0 ]; then

    echo 'No arguments provided.'

else

    echo "Arguments detected."

fi
```

But as soon as I replace the second `echo` with a for-loop, it breaks:

```
if [ $# -le 0 ]; then

    echo 'No arguments provided.'

else

    for i in "$@"
    do

        echo "Arguments detected: $i"

    done

fi
```

I've tried to execute only the for-loop and I'm given an error, so I think the for-loop is wrong somehow, but I don't know how. The error is:

```
bash: C:/Users/Angleton/.bashrc: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: C:/Users/Angleton/.bashrc: line 45: `    fi'
```

Comment: Works for me using `bash-4.3.30`.  Maybe you have some funky whitespace characters in the mix...perhaps try retyping it carefully.

Comment: You can check for funky whitespace or other weird characters by printing the script with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet .bashrc` and see if it prints anything weird (other than a "$" at the end of each line -- that's normal with `cat -e`).

Comment: I only see `$` on the ends.